# How to get the columns of a jface Tree Viewer?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, treeview, jface, treeviewer

Having a reference to a jface `TreeViewer`, how can you get a list of its columns, e.g. `TreeViewerColumn` objects? Something like:

```
TreeViewer treeViewer = (TreeViewer)viewer;
TreeViewerColumn[] treeViewerColumns = treeViewer.getColumns();
```

Is it just me or there isn't an obvious way to do this?

What I'm trying to do is to add editing support for items in Project Explorer. I have a reference to the Project Explorer's tree viewer, but I need to obtain its `TreeViewerColumn` and do:

```
column.setEditingSupport(...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference to the `TreeViewerColumn` is stored in the data of the `TreeColumn`. The following should give you a list of `TreeViewerColumns`:

```
List<TreeViewerColumn> treeViewerColumns = new ArrayList<TreeViewerColumn>();
TreeColumn[] columns = treeViewer.getTree().getColumns();
for (TreeColumn column : columns) {
    Object data = column.getData(Policy.JFACE + ".columnViewer");
    if (data instanceof TableViewerColumn) {
        TreeViewerColumn tvc = (TreeViewerColumn) data;
        treeViewerColumns.add(tvc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The above snippet does exactly that, but the Project Explorer's tree viewer appears to have no explicitly added columns - treeViewer.getTree().getColumns() returns an empty array. Anyway, this is another question.